# Metro Games in c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to use DirectX in C# to create metro game for windows store? XNA isn't supported as far as i know so what are capabilities to create game for metro?

Comment: Another useful link http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Sharpening-your-Metro-CXAML-projects-with-DirectX-and-SharpDX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is possible, you can use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), new version supports Windows store apps (WinRT).

SharpDX is open source project and you can use it in your commercial applications without a charge, more here : http://sharpdx.org/about/licensing

here is the example of usage and some tips :

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Making-Modern-UI-Managed-DirectX-Apps-with-SharpDX-Updated-for-Win-8VS2012-RTM

Comment: thank you, one more question - is it free for commercial use?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage your XNA investment via [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) which in turn relies on SharpDX.  Check out [Bob Familiar's blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobfamiliar/archive/2012/08/01/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-1-overview.aspx) to get started.  (And yes, it's also free).

Answer (score 0):

I you know C++, you can write the graphic part of your project in a separate Library written in C++ and using DirectX directly.